# The consequences of changing perf_event_mlock_kb

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, perf

I'm trying to understand the exact consequences of changing `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb`.

- The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) for perf says

  > Maximum number of pages an unprivileged user can mlock(2). The default is 516 (kB).
- The [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt) says

  > Control size of per-cpu ring buffer not counted agains mlock limit.
  >   The default value is 512 + 1 page

What confuses me is that both sources use two different units - the number of pages and Kb of memory. At the same time, the postfix `_kb` of the name implies that the file defines the number of Kb.

Is my understanding correct that the wording implies that the number should be devisable by the page size and if I set the file to 8046 on a machine with two vCPUs then perf will be able to take up to 16Mb of memory for the event buffers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the kernel docs are missing a unit.

It should be 512 **kiB** + 1 page = 516 kiB, matching the filename and the perf man page.  The actual filename wouldn't still be named `_kb` if it had different units.

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb` on my system shows `516`, so that pretty much confirms that it's in kiB.

> number should be devisable by the page size

Yes, the number should be divisible by 4 to make the size divisible by the 4k page size, on x86.

If not, the kernel presumably rounds up or down, IDK which.

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8c2ffd9174779014c3fe1f96d9dc3641d9175f00/tools/perf/util/evlist.c#L917), it's rounded down to the nearest power of 2. However, if it is zero, it seems to be rounded to the largest power of 2 that can be represented. But later this huge value is checked again against the mlock limit in [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8c2ffd9174779014c3fe1f96d9dc3641d9175f00/kernel/events/core.c#L5564) function, so it seems to work correctly.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I wonder if there's any validation of that value anywhere else, like in a path that accepts writes to that sysctl? 
 But yes, the code that actually chooses a buffer size takes that size and subtracts 1 page (`page_size/1024`), and rounds that down to a power of 2, so that's why a default of 512kiB + 1 page makes sense.

Comment: But why does it have to subtract 1 page? I think `perf_event_mlock_kb_in_pages` returns the total number of pages to allocate. I was not able to find the code that sets `perf_event_mlock_kb`. Note that the corresponding variable name is called `sysctl_perf_event_mlock`.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I have *no* idea why it does that.  Maybe it wants to leave 1 page of lockable memory unused for this, for some reason?